# Will there be any memory leaks if I access my resources statically from My Application class?

Tags: android, kotlin

Will there be any memory leaks if I access resources statically from My Application class like so:

```
class App : Application() {    
    companion object {
        fun getResources(): Resources {
            return this.getResources()
        }
    }   
}
```

---

I was looking for a way to access my resources directly from my view models without passing a context object I just had to use AndroidViewModel instead of ViewModel from android arch components.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

[Companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) are not static, as the documentation describes:

> Note that, even though the members of companion objects look like static members in other languages, at runtime those are still instance members of real objects, and can, for example, implement interfaces

Comment: Even if you add the @JvmStatic annotation?

Comment: Then you'll have a real static field in the bytecode, that's true. But do you use it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understood what you mean by your question.
My goal is to access my string resources directly from my view models without passing a context object...any ideas on how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use companion object like this to get access to the `App` class. In your example, `this` refers to companion object itself, thus you're creating endless recursive call: `this.getResources()` just calls itself since `this == App.Companion`.

You cannot access `App` instance from its companion object, but you can access your companion instance from `App` class. That means, if you want to access your app context globally, you have to do smth like this:

```
class App {
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    appContext = this
  }

  companion object {
    lateinit var appContext: Context

    fun getResources(): Resources = appContext.resources
  }
}
```

Comment: I just learnt that the hard way lol..I can't really say I understood the cause of the endless loop?